# How do I apply count and distinct on multiple columns from table1 before inserting into table2

Tags: sql, postgresql

Situation:

Our company just purchased 20 million rows from a vendor. The vendor inserted the data from Excel into TABLE1 (RDBMS is postgresql) and unfortunately TABLE1 doesn't have a PK. My manager wants me to insert all 20 million rows into TABLE2 but with distinct records only.

EMPCODE is the only column with unique values.
TABLE2 is empty prior to insertion.
TABLE1 doesn't have a primary key and last insert date or date_updated column.
I created TABLE2 with a primary key, int NOT NULL identity primary key.

What is the correct sql script to get the correct count to get the desired results?

```
insert into TABLE2 (EMPCODE, FN, LN, STATE, TYPE)
select distinct(EMPCODE), FN, LN, STATE, TYPE from table1
```

or

```
insert into TABLE2 (EMPCODE, FN, LN, STATE, TYPE)
select distinct(EMPCODE, FN, LN, STATE, TYPE) from table1
```

or

```
insert into TABLE2 (EMPCODE, FN, LN, STATE, TYPE)
select EMPCODE, FN, LN, LAST(STATE), TYPE from table1
group by EMPCODE, FN, LN, STATE, TYPE
```

TABLE1

```
EMPCODE  FirstName  LastName        STATE   TYPE

ID111    Fred       Perry           CO      CONSULTANT
ID111    Fred       Perry           UT      CONSULTANT
ID111    Fred       Perry           AZ      CONSULTANT
ID215    Tommy      Hilfiger        IL      INTERN
ID215    Tommy      Hilfiger        IN      INTERN
ID215    Tommy      Hilfiger        OH      INTERN
ID215    Tommy      Hilfiger        NY      INTERN
ID467    David      Abercrombie     TX      REGULAR
ID467    David      Abercrombie     CA      REGULAR
ID875    Ezra       Fitch           NV      TERMINATED
ID875    Ezra       Fitch           OR      TERMINATED
ID875    Ezra       Fitch           WA      TERMINATED
ID875    Ezra       Fitch           UT      TERMINATED
ID875    Ezra       Fitch           AZ      TERMINATED
```

Desired result in TABLE2

```
EMPCODE  FirstName  LastName    STATE   TYPE

ID111    Fred      Perry        CO      CONSULTANT
ID215    Tommy     Hilfiger     IL      INTERN
ID467    David     Abercrombie  TX      REGULAR
ID875    Ezra      Fitch        NV      TERMINATED
```

The problem is that I'm unable to see all data (RAM issues and pgadmin4 very slow) to decide which sql script works best.

Comment: Could you please explain why from all these records ID111    Fred       Perry           CO      CONSULTANT
ID111    Fred       Perry           UT      CONSULTANT
ID111    Fred       Perry           AZ      CONSULTANT   You need Fred Perry from CO and not from UT or AZ?

Comment: The data in table1 are raw data and were scraped by a vendor from the internet. Per the business stakeholder's requirements, all I need to do is to get the top row for each EMPCODE/FN and LN. The problem is that there's no primary key and dateupdated column to apply Max function.

Comment: Then it seems,your task has a lot of right decisions. Could you please start with something like SELECT W.EMPCODE,W.FirstName,W.LastName,W.STATE,W.TYPE
FROM
(
SELECT Y.EMPCODE , Y.FirstName ,Y.LastName, Y. STATE  ,Y. TYPE,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY Y.EMPCODE ORDER BY Y.FIRSTNAME,Y.LASTNAME,Y.STATE,Y.TYPE)AS XCOL
FROM YOURTABLE AS Y
)AS W WHERE W.XCOL=1;

Comment: I'm lost early on . . . is "code" the same as "empcode"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Postgres and you want one arbitrary row per `empcode`, then you can use `distinct on`

```
insert into TABLE2 (EMPCODE, FN, LN, STATE, TYPE)
    select distinct on (EMPCODE) EMPCODE, FN, LN, STATE, TYPE
    from table1
    order by EMPCODE;
```

This will not prevent duplicates that are already in `table2`.  If you want to avoid such duplicates, then create a unique index or constraint on `table2(empcode)` and use an `on conflict` clause.